# Why isn't any Flet code running on my system?

Tags: python, flutter, pycharm, flet

im trying to make an app with Python Flet and i thought it would be good to try a simple hello world program first, and so i did. As the tutorial said to `pip install flet` that worked. then i tried the code

```py
import flet as ft

def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.add(ft.Text(value="Hello, world!"))

ft.app(target=main)
```

this error:

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10825 for the file /Users/turtle/.flet/bin/flet-0.12.2/Flet.app.
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner

Process finished with exit code 0
```

also im using pycharm CE on macOs (10.13.6 intel processor) if thats a problem

Comment: If an exact example from the tutorial doesn't work, you have a tech support question that is better asked at the project's bug tracker, not here. If any further information is needed to solve the problem, they will have a better idea of what is needed than anyone here would.

Comment: I just think that this is a problem with Flet or my system, probably not the cide

Comment: That would be a reason *not* to ask here. That said: a [quick search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=LSOpenURLsWithRole) does seem to imply that this is a Mac-specific issue.